# If the algebraic expression of a transcendental number is algebraic, is the number algebraic?

Tags: field-theory, transcendental-numbers

For instance, if the ‘silver ratio’ of a transcendental number is algebraic, how would someone classify that number? …. perhaps a special subset of transcendental numbers?

Also, perhaps related: are there classifications of transcendental numbers such as the set of this category of numbers which can be expressed as infinite product or arithmetic series, and the set of those that cannot be?

Thank you for any thoughts on this.

Comment: The answer is immediately no because transcendental numbers are not algebraic. I think your title has a typo

Comment: Any real number can be expressed as a suitable infinite product of rationals (write $x = \sum_{n \geq 1}x_n$, then the product $\prod_{n \geq 1}\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_n}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n - 1}x_{n}}$ converges to $x$). If by arithmetic series, you mean constant difference, a finite arithmetic series of rationals is rational, an an infinite arithmetic series always diverges. If you just mean an infinite sum, every real number is clearly an infinite sum, by decimal expansion.

Comment: If an "algebraic expression" of a transcendental number is algebraic ($F(x)=a$, $x$ transcendental, $a,F$ algebraic), than the transcendental number is the root of an algebraic expression $G(x)=F(x)-y$, leading to a contradiction. The "algebraic expression", which is a very vague notation, is usually taken to be a non-constant polynomial. Otherwise if the "algebraic expression" is a constant, than the statement can be satisfied, but it would be meaningless. As for the latter, every real number can be written as an infinite sum of rationals (why?) and infinite product of rationals (why?).

Comment: newby, I think you had better give a precise example of what you mean by the `silver ratio" of a number. In symbols, all symbols, if we call the transcendental $t,$ what is the silver ratio  of it?

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  By silver ratio, I mean  $(n^2 + 1)^.5 + n$

Comment: The transcendental number in the equation is $e^(2*pi)$

Comment: 1 + 1/ this number.  Multiplied by the original number to the power of 1/5

Comment: The relation was discovered by Ramanujan.  However, he expressed it (to my knowledge) as a nested arithmetic infinite series.  But since such series are the equivalent of silver ratios, there is a finite algebraic iteration involving $e^pi$ and the golden ratio.  Therefore the number seems special as a particular transcendental number.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients, or with rational coefficients, or with algebraic coefficients, or a rational function with algebraic coefficients, or an algebraic function with algebraic coefficients, and $t$ is a transcendental number, then $f(t)$ is a transcendental number. If Ramanujan said otherwise, then Ramanujan was wrong ––– but, more likely, someone else misunderstood what Ramanujan was trying to say.

Comment: So, you’re saying that if:  pi squared minus one over pi happens to equal the square root of three plus one, then pi must be regarded as algebraic?

Comment: I'm saying that $(\pi^2-1)/\pi$ can't possibly equal $\sqrt3+1$, since the latter is algebraic whilst the former is transcendental. I'm saying that if $t$ is transcendental, then $(t^2-1)/t$, and $t^2-(1/t)$, are guaranteed to be transcendental.

Comment: Then $e^pi$ is not transcendental.  Euler said that there must be no finite algebraic method to the number.

Comment: My secondary question might be answered as:  Liouville transcendental numbers.  Those that may be ‘approached’ by infinite series, such as $e$ and $pu$ and $e^pi$, may be examples of such a subset of transcendental numbers.  But I am not certain on this.   Also,  $e^pi$ may be special in that it can be approached by an infinite series of itself. A sort of infinite nested series of infinite product series.  I don’t know of another transcendental number for which that is the case.

Comment: Perhaps this characteristic is unique among transcendental numbers and is related to why it has an algebraic function that gives an algebraic solution.  Any thoughts?

Comment: 1) Please take some time to learn how to format math on this site, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference When you write $e^pi$, I'm going to assume you mean $e^{\pi}$. 2) Math has come a long way since Euler. 3) I don't know what "no finite algebraic method to the number" means. 4) $e^{\pi}$ is transcendental, though this was proved long after Euler's time. 5) Every number, transcendental or not, can be approached by an infinite series (of, say, rational numbers). Continued...

Comment: ... 6) $e$ and $e^{\pi}$ are not Liouville numbers. I don't know what you mean by $pu$. 7) I don't know what you mean by $e^{\pi}$ "has an algebraic function that gives an algebraic solution". 8) Your confusion on these matters is broad and deep. I suggest you sit down with a good Number Theory textbook that will set you straight.